# How to make ofstream constructor fail when opening non-existing file?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I want my open of non-existent output file to fail. Only if the output file exists I want open succeed. How can I do this with ofstream constructor?

Comment: You can [make streams throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979396/can-cout-throw-an-exception) on failure, but as far as I know it can't be done for their constructors since it requires an instance to enable the behavior.

Comment: You can use `std::filesystem::exists` if you have access to c++17. Otherwise I would try to open the file for reading first. If that fails it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why was the question downvoted? It is a valid question, even though there is no good answer.

Comment: @super existing and being readable are very different things.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux and even when you do enable exceptions, they are super inconvenient to use. I am afraid, we have to admit that bad exception specification is one (of the several) shortcomings of standard streams.

Comment: @SergeyA Maybe in the general case, but if you are expecting to write to a file, being able to open it for reading is probably a safe indication of it's existence.

Comment: @super of course not! File can easily be write-only for you.

Comment: @SergeyA Nitpicking 101? I never said it's a 100% guarantee, I said **probably**.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux what you say is true for the constructor. But, you can construct a default-constructed `std::ofstream`, enable exceptions on it, and then call `open()` on it. It will then throw if the file fails to open.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What you say is also true, but the question asks *"How can I do this with ofstream constructor?"*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux actually, the real question is how to make the constructor *fail*, not how to make the constructor *throw an exception*. There is a difference. I was simply commenting on your comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you're right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ofstream`'s constructor takes a [`std::ios_base::openmode`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) that specifies how the file should be opened.  By default this value is set to `ios_base::out`, which will create the file if it does not exist.  You can provide your own mode though, and if you use `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in` then no file will be created.  That would make your code look like this:

```
std::ofstream fout("some_file.ext", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in);
```

Comment: See [`std::basic_filebuf::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) for the supported combinations of flags and what they do together.

Comment: Did ios::nocreate exist in some version of c++ as described here https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/99au/assignments/fileIO.html

Comment: @RanjitKumar No, that never made it into the C++98 standard.  If you look at the headers in the linked to post you'll see they are doing `#include <iostream.h>` which was the pre C++ standard way.  It might work in a compiler like TurboC++ but not in any standard complaint compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the constructor of `std::ofstream`.

What you can do, is define your own custom stream class. Your own stream can check whether the file exists, and fail if it does not. If the file exists, you can delegate the functionality to an ofstream contained as a data member.

Another approach that doesn't require a custom stream might be to change your code to not even attempt to construct the stream until you've first verified that the file exists.